# Error Class 'App\Providers\App' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, update, laravel-4

Estoy actualizando por fases un Laravel ajeno (no lo he instalado yo) desde la versión **4.1 a 5.8**

Todo iba bien hasta llegar a la **5.0**, que me devuelve el siguiente error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   Class
>   'App\Providers\App' not found

Ya he buscado por Internet pero nadie hace referencia a esa clase. Sí de los Providers, pero no de la App en cuestión.

Este es mi archivo de **Composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "pda/pheanstalk": "~3.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Http/Controllers",
        "app/Models",
        "app/Console/Commands"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

Aquí los Providers de **config/app.php** (No aparece el App)

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',

    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',


],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    'Auth'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
    'Blade'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
    'Bus'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus',
    'Cache'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
    'Config'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
    'Cookie'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
    'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
    'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
    'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
    'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
    'File'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
    'Hash'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
    'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
    'Inspiring' => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring',
    'Lang'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
    'Log'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
    'Mail'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
    'Password'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
    'Queue'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
    'Redirect'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
    'Redis'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
    'Request'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
    'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
    'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
    'Schema'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
    'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
    'Storage'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage',
    'URL'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
    'Validator' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
    'View'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',

    'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
    'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',


],
```

Y en mi carpeta de **App/Providers** solo dispongo de **AppServiceProvider**, **BusServiceProvider**, **ConfigServiceProvider**, **EventServiceProvider** y **RouteServiceProvider**

En ninguno de esos archivos, ni en todo el proyecto, aparece dicha ruta. He seguido los pasos de Laravel para actualizar y algo se me escapa o algo está mal en el Laravel original.

¿Alguien puede orientarme sobre el tema?

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Comprobaste la clase ServiceProvider en _vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php_ ? En esa clase hay un constructor para todos los Providers que extienden de SerivceProvider. Aparte, en tu congif/app, por lo menos por lo que yo conozco en versiones superiores a la 5, para todas las clases debes poner la constante ::class, ejemplo: _'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider'::class_ . Espero haberte podido echar un mano con los datos que disponemos

Comment: como estas haciendo la actualizacíon? Como dice [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0)?: > El método recomendado de actualización es crear una nueva instalación de Laravel 5.0 y luego copiar los archivos de aplicación únicos de su sitio 4.2 en la nueva aplicación.

Comment: Si, esos son los pasos que estuve siguiendo, salvo la sección del caché que no usamos. Hasta 4.2 nos arranca sin problemas, pero en el salto al 5.0 es cuando nos queda algo, creo que tiene que ser un tema del namespacing.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
rm ./bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Yo tengo el mismo error y esto funcionó para mí.